# How to switch to previously opened header/source in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I've found this [list of C/C++ source code shortcuts for Eclipse IDEs](http://blog.atollic.com/editor-power-130-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-plus-the-only-one-you-need-to-know) and it is very helpful but it lacks one very useful feature.

Say I'm editing xxx.cpp and after that I've opened yyy.cpp. Now I want to re-open xxx.cpp without closing yyy.cpp. Ideally it would work such that pressing the same combination twice opens yyy.cpp. Do xxx.cpp -> combination -> yyy.zpp -> combination -> xxx.cpp.

Is it possible? I'm using Eclipse CDT (STM32CubeIDE).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the shortcuts for this are Alt-Left, Alt-Right (c) http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/eclipseCDT8.0-cheatsheet.pdf